# Button interaction failed

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

i have problem because i made smth in ButtonClickEvent and it works well but when someone click button under this button i have error "This interaction failed", i have to finish in code action with button or what can i do with this ?

Declaring button:

```java
channel.sendFile(file,"paint.png").setEmbeds(embed.build()).setActionRow(Button.success("veryfication","VERYFI!")).queue();
```

And ButtonClickEvent:

```
public void onButtonClick(ButtonClickEvent e){
    if(e.getButton() != null) {
        if (e.getButton().getId().equalsIgnoreCase("veryfication")) {
            final Member member = e.getMember();
            if (member != null && member.getRoles() != null) {
                if (!member.getRoles().contains(e.getGuild().getRoleById("920701070831939669"))) {
                    e.getGuild().addRoleToMember(member, e.getGuild().getRoleById("920701070831939669")).queue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Image:

[image: Button error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discord requires that you *acknowledge* the button interaction. This can be done with one of the following:

- [deferReply](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/Interaction.html#deferReply(boolean))
  Reply with a "bot is thinking..." message and edit it later
- [reply](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/Interaction.html#reply(java.lang.String))
  Reply with a message
- [deferEdit](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/components/ComponentInteraction.html#deferEdit())
  Do nothing (or edit later)
- [editMessage](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/components/ComponentInteraction.html#editMessage(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message))
  Edit the message the button was clicked on

If you only want to acknowledge the button was clicked, without responding with a message or editing the message, you can simply use `event.deferEdit().queue();`.